# dev_appserver.py doesn't run the app engine, instead it asks how do I want to open .py files for windows 10

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am currently running a tutorial for python on google app engine using the python docs samples repository. When I try to run dev_appserver.py in the hello_world folder, it doesn't open the app engine locally, but instead asks me how I want to display .py files, which if I select an application, will open it as a python text file instead.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Have you install python on your windows 10 machine?

Comment: @ChristoforusSurjoputro yes I have installed python 2,7 using anaconda

Comment: How do you run it, @shirleyc40? It should be python dev_appserver.py. Or maybe you can change .py file in properties to opened using python.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably best off using the command line to start up the local development server.

1. From the Start menu, you can search for `cmd` to open the command prompt. You might need to right click it and choose "Run as administrator."
2. Change directories to where your application's `app.yaml` file is located. For example:

   ```
   cd C:\Users\<myname>\<myfolder_with_app.yaml>\
   ```
3. Run the `dev_appserver.py` against the current directory (indicated by the dot):

   ```
   python dev_appserver.py .
   ```

If you get a command not found error, then you need to install Python. If you get a could not find the `dev_appserver.py` file then your `PATH` environment variable doesn't have the SDK path in it. See [Using the Local Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server) for more information including troubleshooting.